# Find last numeric cell in column above current cell, when column also can contain text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

We have a column in our spreadsheet for `Step Number` that looks like this (each line is a new cell/row):

```
1
2
3
SKIP
4
SKIP
SKIP
5
```

Because of those `SKIP` cells, we can't use a simple formula like `=B1+1`.

Before we replace a step number cell with SKIP, we duplicate the "source" spreadsheet tab, then replace steps with SKIP if they are not necessary.

Is there a way to auto-increment numbers such that if we replace a cell with SKIP, all the subsequent numbers would decrease by 1? For example, search for the closest cell above in a column with a numeric value, then +1. So if we replaced that formula in a cell with the text SKIP, it would adjust any numbers lower in the column.

I figure there's probably some super complex solution, such as "determine row number, count the number of SKIP cells with a lower row number, do arithmetic" but that seems pretty messy and hard to get right (not to mention I'm not sure how to do that)

Thanks!

Comment: can you share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result? You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)

Comment: I believe this is doable with Google Apps Script with an onEdit() function. Would you like a Google Apps Script based solution?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are starting with a list of sequential numbers from 1 to X and need to replace some of them with "SKIP" (or any non-number, for that matter).  After that all numbers below that replacement should be reduced by 1. This can be done as follows:

1. Place the number 1 in the first row.
2. Use the formula `=COUNT(A$1:A1)+1` in the next row below, and extend it downwards (e.g., `=COUNT(A$1:A2)+1` in the next row, and so on). This can be easily done by dragging the formula down.

Now, when you replace any number in the sequence with text, `count` functions in the cells below will count 1 cell less since it recognizes only numbers ([documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093620?hl=en)).  [Sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16jGJaIiO2H1khfzqAmvU1diyQmQmAO8m608N7dLq_9M/edit#gid=0) (read only, copy to edit).